# slf4j-simple logger not working on a Maven Vertx project

Tags: java, slf4j, vert.x

Below is my `logback.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
     <!-- <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern> -->
     <Pattern>%-30(%date{ISO8601,UTC} [%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{32} %line - %msg%n </Pattern>
   </layout>
 </appender>  
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <file>logs/search_service.log</file>
   <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
     <!-- <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern> -->
     <Pattern>%-30(%date{ISO8601,UTC} [%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{32} %line - %msg%n </Pattern>
   </encoder>
   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/search_service.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
    <!-- <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize> -->
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
   </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>  
  <!-- <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root> -->
</configuration>
```

Following is the maven dependency I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Following is the way I am using it in my Main class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Mainclass extends AbstractVerticle {
    final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mainclass.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LOGGER.info("Hi.");
    }
}
```

Following is the way I am deploying the my fat jar:

```
java -DconfigPath="myconfig.conf" -DLogback.configurationFile="logback.xml" -jar myapp.jar
```

My problem is when I run the above command it gives me three warnings as follows and there is no logging and no log files are created:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Which logging backend do you want to use? logback or slf4j-simple? Also you need to include log4j-over-slf4j.

Comment: Are they different? I am sorry if my question is naive. I have just started working in the application side and learning. I want to use logback to get a logger which would accept the supplied logback file in the terminal and log info and error messages to log file and may be console as well.

Comment: @user3243499 slf4j is a façade that presents a unified logging API throughout your app. Behind that façade you must configure a logging implementation. The [*Logback*](https://logback.qos.ch/) project is a full-featured direct implementation of the slf4j API. You must separately download and configure Logback in addition to slf4j. The *slf4j-simple* bundled with slf4j is also a direct implementation of the slf4j API but is very limited in features. For other logging frameworks built without regard for slf4j (such as log4j) you must employ an adapter.

Comment: Thanks Basil for your explanation. Is there maven dependency which I can add to my pom file and logging would start working using the above approach wherein I supply the logback file? If there is any specific code snippets required to be added in my class file, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of confusion in your configuration and classpath. You're referencing a logback.xml file, you have a Maven dependency on slf4j-simple, and you are getting messages from Log4j. Logback, slf4j-simple, and Log4j are three completely different logging systems which SLF4J can interface with.

So let's take a step back for a minute. The point of SLF4J is that it is a "facade" (that's the "F" in the acronym) for whatever real logging system you want to use. This means that if your code logs using the SLF4J API, you could change your logging system as needed. More importantly, if the libraries you call log using the SLF4J API, you can just connect SLF4J to the logging system that the rest of your project is using.

The way you configure SLF4J to use the desired real logging system is by including a [binding](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) for it on your classpath. A binding is what redirects the log messages from the SLF4J API to the real underlying logging system. Most bindings would also require you to have the real logging system on your classpath (that is, if you're using Log4j 1.2, you'd include slf4j-log4j12 as well as log4j on your classpath). Other bindings, such as Logback and slf4j-simple, act as both the binding as well as the actual logging system, since they're designed to work with SLF4J from the beginning. You want exactly one binding on your classpath, and you want no other logging systems than the one you want to use on your classpath. But you need to figure out which logging system you actually want to use, since there are many options, just like with any technology decision.

Since you're using Maven to manage the dependencies on your classpath, you can run "mvn [dependency:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)" to see the list of all dependencies, and what your dependencies are bringing in. That may help you figure out what bindings and logging systems you and your libraries are using.

Well-behaved libraries intended for use with SLF4J will just include slf4j-api, since the binding should just be used by the main application. If you have a library that tries to use its own logging system, you may need to use Maven to [exclude](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions) it. You can redirect other logging systems to use SLF4J instead with [a bridge](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) if needed.

Once you have your dependencies sorted out so that there is only one logging system connected to SLF4J, and any dependencies that want to use a different logging system are bridged to that system, then you should be able to configure that logging system however it works (such as logback.xml if you're using Logback) to see your logging.